# HTTP 400 BAD_REQUEST between dockerised Django and Spring boot service

Tags: python, django, spring-boot, docker

I am running Django and a Spring boot application as Dockerised services with the same Docker volume and network.

For one of the requirement, I am making a request from my Django service to the Spring boot service using Python's request module, as shown below,

```
res = requests.post(
            f'http://{spring_host}:8080/getTranslatedAsFile/',
            data={
                'document-json-dump': json.dumps(data),
                "doc_req_res_params": json.dumps(res_paths),
                "doc_req_params": json.dumps(params_data),
                  })
```

Here `data`, `res_paths` and `params_data` are python dicts. `data` contains keys and values depending on the content of the document. More the content (e.g. more words, sentences) more will be keys & values of `data`.

The request is received by the Spring boot service at the controller as shown below,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getTranslatedAsFile/")
    public String getTranslatedAsFile(@RequestParam("doc_req_params") String docReqParams,
                                      @RequestParam("doc_req_res_params") String docReqResParams,
                                      @RequestParam("document-json-dump") String documentJsonDump)
            throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Document document = objectMapper.readValue(documentJsonDump, Document.class);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
        DocumentReqParameters documentReqParameters = objectMapper1
                                                .readValue(docReqParams, DocumentReqParameters.class);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
        DocumentReqResourceParameters documentReqResourceParameters = objectMapper2
                                                .readValue(docReqResParams, DocumentReqResourceParameters.class);

        return  documentProcessService.translate(documentReqParameters, documentReqResourceParameters, document);
        
    }
```

When I make a request for document with less content (< 50000 words), i.e `data` with less keys and values, I am receiving a `HTTP 200 response` from Spring boot service and able to process the response data.

But when I make a request for document with more content (approx > 50000 words), I am getting a `HTTP 400 BAD_REQUEST` response. Shown below is the error log from Spring boot,

```
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.756  INFO 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.762 DEBUG 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/getTranslatedAsFile/", parameters={}
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.770 DEBUG 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ailaysa.translate.v1.controller.FileController#getTranslatedAsFile(String, String, String)
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.788 DEBUG 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public java.lang.String com.ailaysa.translate.v1.controller.FileController.getTranslatedAsFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException: Required String parameter 'doc_req_params' is not present
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.792  WARN 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'doc_req_params' is not present]
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.793 DEBUG 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 400 BAD_REQUEST
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.801 DEBUG 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.804 DEBUG 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.ailaysa.translate.v1.controller.ErrorController#handleError(HttpServletRequest)
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.819 DEBUG 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected '*/*' given [*/*]
spring-service-web1_1  | 2022-08-14 03:02:32.980 DEBUG 49 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 400
```

Any suggestion to solve this issue will be highly helpful.

Comment: My guess is that django doens't send the whole json. Could you check out what is actually sent? i.e. dump the `data` to log

Comment: @grekierSure. I will check.